# iOS how to show a date in another language,

Tags: ios

I've recently been working on a French version of our application use `NSLocalizedStrings`, so far everything is working great.

But my problem now is with dates. I show dates often in my application, in different formats, depending on the situation.

Ex:

```
-Fri Feb 22, 2013
-Monday February 18, 2013
-Feb 18
-Dec 5, 2012
```

The thing is, dates in French are not only different in terms of the name of the month, but also the order in which month, day and year appear.

Ex:

```
-Dec 5, 2012 would be 5 Dec 2012
-Monday February 18, 2013 would be Lundi le 18 Fevrier 2013.
```

I have the individual month/day names in my `Localizable.string` files, but how do I manage the order of how it's displayed.

Should I have an if statement that checks the current device language like so?:

```
NSString *currentLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"fr"])
{
    //Handle French logic
}
```

This is probably not the best way to go about it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSDateFormatter`. For example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);
```

`NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` will automatically format the date according to the user's preference (English, French, etc.).

If you need custom styling and the app runs in iOS 4.0+, you can use a custom template in your date formatter:

```
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EdMMMyyy" options:0
                                          locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];

NSString *todayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"todayString: %@", todayString);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I have the dates formatted as they are in my question?

Comment: @PaulG Check my updated answer. If you need to present the date with a custom style, the `dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` method returns a custom format string according to the user's locale (or any other locale). This will take care of order and other things that are specific to a locale.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Why is it that dMMM and MMMd both give me 2 Jan??? Shouldn't the second one give me Jan 2??

Comment: Sorry, I figured out that the date format I'm looking for (Jan 2) is American, wheras my Region Format is set to Canada (which I guess uses the British format of 2 Jan). Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an NSDateFormatter and feed it your desired NSLocale like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"nl_NL"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE d MMMM yyyy HH:mm";
```

'EEEE' is the full name of the day of the week, which, in my case, will be displayed in dutch.

Comment: This changes the wording just fine but not the order. Wednesday 2 January 2013 00:00 turns into mercredi 2 janvier 2013 00:00 which is fine for French, but English dates are not written like that.

Answer (score 1):

Set proper locale to your NSDateFormatter when you convert date to string, then date formatter will handle all specifics of formats depending on user settings for you:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = ... // Create and setup formatter
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]]; 
// Now you can convert date to string
```

Answer (score 1):

That's probaly much easier:
There is something which is called

```
NSDateFormatterShortStyle,
NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
NSDateFormatterLongStyle
```

Set Date and Time components individually:

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; 
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

Ios will format that correctly if the language of the user.

Further look at [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the class function `localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:` in `NSDateFormatter` before attempting to use the NSDateFormatter and a template (from [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)):

Example:

```
[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateTime dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

You can select both different date and time outputs of various lengths detailed in the docs.

Apple documentation: [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)